# Are resampled images actually smaller in size than non-resampled images?

Tags: php, image, file, resampling

When I started working with images in PHP, I learned images should be **resized** and **resampled** to reduce file size. I'm taking `resizing` here to be *reducing an image height and width without intentionally altering image quality* and `resampling` to be *resizing and intentionally altering image quality with imageconvolution() function*. When comparing a group of images of the same dimensions, one resampled with PHP, the other not, I noticed not-so-subtle differences in the file sizes. These are my findings for one set of images, and they were similar to the other sets:

> **Resampled and Resized Image:**

1. **Dimensions:** 550 * 366
2. **File Size:** 25.19KB

> **Resized Image without Resampling:**

1. **Dimensions:** 550 * 366
2. **File Size:** 20.89KB

> **Original Image:**

1. **Dimensions:** 4896 * 3264
2. **File Size:** 1.1MB

The resampled image is `4.3KB` bigger than the non-resampled image. This difference is relatively small, but if the resampled image turns out to be greater than the non-resampled image, what then is the importance of resampling? Is this a rare occurrence? Does this only happen to `jpeg` files?
**N/B:** I worked with `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecopyresampled`, and `imageconvolution` (when resampling).

Comment: what are the images extensions in your examples?

Comment: They're all `jpg` images.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of an image always requires resampling in some form or another. See the definition of resampling at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Mathematical. The difference in the final file size is probably entirely due to the different scaling techniques producing visually different images, which **compress differently** by the final JPEG algorithm. E.g. the larger file contains more details or graininess, which doesn't compress as well. You will have to choose which resizing algorithm and compression format you prefer and balance visual quality vs. file size of the end result.